# Have one event happen after another one finishes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm trying to create a sequence of events as described below:

1) The user would click on `.post-link` which would scroll the page to the top if it isn't there already.

2) The `#project-container` would open up revealing the `#loading-animation`.

3) The post would load via Ajax.

---

Right now, when I click on `.post-link`, everything seems to happen at once. How can I format the code below to make sure that one event happens after another one finishes?

Essentially, [this is what I'm trying to recreate](http://themetrust.com/demos/reveal/). When you click on a post, notice how the hidden container opens up to reveal the loading animation, and then once the content has loaded, it opens up to display the content.

**JS**

```
$('.post-link').click(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop : 0
    },500, function() {
        $('#loading-animation').show();
    });

    var post_id = $(this).attr('rel');
    var ajaxURL = site.ajaxurl;

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: ajaxURL,
        data: {'action': 'load-content', post_id: post_id },
        success: function(response) {
            $('#project-container').html(response);
            $('#loading-animation').hide();
        return false;
        }
    });

});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="primary" class="content-area">
    <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">

        <div id="project-container">
            <img id="loading-animation" src="http://i.imgur.com/5RMfW8P.gif" style="display:none">
        </div>

        <!-- Start the loop -->
        <?php $home_query = new WP_Query('post_type=projects');

        while($home_query->have_posts()) : $home_query->the_post(); ?>

            <a class="post-link" href="#" rel="<?php the_ID(); ?>">
                <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
                    <div class="post-info">
                        <h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
                    </div>
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail( "home-thumb", array( 'class' => 'grayscale grayscale-fade') ); ?>
                </article><!-- #post-## -->
            </a>

        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php wp_reset_postdata(); // reset the query ?>

    </main><!-- #main -->
</div><!-- #primary -->
```

**PHP**

```
/**
 * Enqueue scripts and styles.
 */
function starter_scripts() {
    wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_register_script( 'jquery', includes_url( '/js/jquery/jquery.js' ), false, NULL, true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-effects-core');

    wp_enqueue_style( 'starter-style', get_stylesheet_uri() );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'gray', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/min/jquery.gray.min.js', array('jquery'), '', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'includes', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/min/includes.min.js', array('jquery'), '', true );
    wp_localize_script( 'includes', 'site', array(
                'theme_path' => get_template_directory_uri(),
                'ajaxurl'    => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')
            )
    );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'starter_scripts' );

/**
 * Return the post content to the AJAX call
 */
function my_load_ajax_content () {
    $args = array(
        'p' => $_POST['post_id'], 
        'post_type' => 'projects' 
        );
    $post_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    while( $post_query->have_posts() ) : $post_query->the_post(); ?>

    <div class="post-container">

        <?php the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title">', '</h1>' ); ?>

        <?php the_content(); ?>

    </div><!-- #post-## -->

    <?php       
    endwhile;           
    exit;
}
add_action ( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_load-content', 'my_load_ajax_content' );
add_action ( 'wp_ajax_load-content', 'my_load_ajax_content' );
```

Comment: You should look into [promises](https://www.promisejs.org/). While the solution below by @Tyr should work, it would only start the AJAX call once the animation has completed. With promises however, you can easily have it start the AJAX request first, then once both the AJAX request AND the animation has completed, the results would be shown. It also saves you from the [pyramid of doom](http://survivejs.com/common_problems/pyramid.html).

Comment: I know what you mean, my solution was based on his desired behavior shown in the posted link.

Comment: I would also look into using global methods `ajaxStart(function(){...})` and `ajaxStop(function(){...})`. You could display your loading spinner while the image is being retrieved.

Comment: Can you provide the HTML (not PHP) so we can test? A JSFiddle, Snippet, or Plunk would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put your Ajax call into the .show() function for chaining animations.

http://api.jquery.com/show/

```
$('.post-link').click(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    var post_id = $(this).attr('rel');
    var ajaxURL = site.ajaxurl;

    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop : 0
    },500, function() {
        $('#loading-animation').show(500, function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: ajaxURL,
                data: {'action': 'load-content', post_id: post_id },
                success: function(response) {
                    $('#project-container').html(response);
                    $('#loading-animation').hide();
                    return false;
                }
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: That created a nice chain but when I click on another post after a previous one has loaded, nothing happens. The previous post is still displayed and the new post does not load.

Comment: Are the links inside of your #project-container? If so, then you have to rebind the click event after the ajax call since the links have no reference anymore.

Comment: No, they are not. They are outside the `#project-container`. I updated my post with the HTML.

Comment: Any errors on the console? Add a console.log($(this).attr('rel')); into the handler in the first line to check if the function is called.

Comment: I added in the `console.log` and it shows that when I click on each `.post-link`, the correct ID is being called. However, the post itself does not change.

Comment: @Marcel Yes, but only for the first post I click. After that, the console shows that when I click on other post links, the correct ID is being called; however, the post does not update.

Comment: I don't know if this might be complete nonsense, but did you try to remove the "return false" within the ajax callback?
I myself never return false in ajax callbacks…

Comment: Did you check that the PHP part of it does its job correctly?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68511/discussion-between-marcel-and-j82).

Answer (score 2):

After loading the first post, your #loading-animation is being removed and you cannot interact with it anymore.

Try to load your ajax content into another wrapper element within the #project-container

**HTML**

```
   <div id="project-container">
     <img id="loading-animation" src="http://i.imgur.com/5RMfW8P.gif" style="display:none">
     <div class="ajax-wrapper"></div>
   </div>
```

**JS**

```
      [...]
      success: function(response) {
         $('#project-container .ajax-wrapper').html(response);
         $('#loading-animation').hide();
         return false;
      }
      [...]
```